# i want the value of the instantiated gameobj in unity which is over the photon network in other script so my camera can follow the player

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

```
 public class playeri : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
 {
public GameObject[] playerprefab = new GameObject[1];
public Transform[] spawnpoints; //THIS IS THE SPAWN POINTS FROM WEHRE THE player comes out 



void Start()
{

    // PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
   //followplayer a = GetComponent<followplayer>();
    
            print("hello");
    int randomnumber = Random.Range(0, spawnpoints.Length);
    Transform spawnpoint = spawnpoints[randomnumber];
    int random = Random.Range(0, playerprefab.Length);
    GameObject playertosp = playerprefab[random];
    

          
  GameObject target = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playertosp.name, spawnpoint.position, 
 Quaternion.identity);
     
    
}
```

}

what issue I have is that I want my camera to follow the player that is instantiate over the photon so can anyone tell me how can I do this I am very confused so tell me about this

Comment: But wouldn't you actually only want **this** local player follow his player object? It sounds odd that you want each and everyone's camera to follow this instantiated player object ...

Comment: Yes can you help me that my camera should follow the player over the photon network

Comment: Again: I don't think it should happen over the network at all. You only want to follow **your own** local player. You don't need the network for this. Simply make your local camera now follow the `target` object.